# Australia 476 Visa Application Processing times - from UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, australia

The Australian Subclass 476 skilled-recognised graduate visa for engineers states processing times of:

- 75% of applications: 12 months
- 90% of applications: 16 months

and you can't apply until after you graduate.

These times seem really high and makes it difficult to plan for. I was wondering if coming from the UK the processing times may be lower and the average is only so high because of other countries being more difficult to be approved from?

Any input on processing times is greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Immigration used to release stats on approval/refusal and processing times for visitor visas https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/research-and-statistics/statistics/visa-statistics/visit.
I don't know whether they have something similar for your visa subclass.

Comment: Also, the numbers quoted are 'within' numbers. I.e., 75% of applications processed in 12 months or less. Actual times may be a lot shorter.

Comment: They still do publish stats but i couldn't find any for the 476.